# Excel syntax for SQL string

Tags: sql, excel

I need to write an SQL insert statement in cells that reference another cell.  What would be the correct syntax to do this? The part that needs to reference another cell is written below as {value of cell} :

```
INSERT INTO map.UserSurveys (surveyId,userId,activeQuestions) VALUES (50, {value of cell}, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value is a number:

```
="INSERT INTO map.UserSurveys (surveyId,userId,activeQuestions) VALUES (50, " & A1 & ", 1)"
```

If the value is a string:

```
="INSERT INTO map.UserSurveys (surveyId,userId,activeQuestions) VALUES (50, '" & A1 & "', 1)"
```

---

In both cases replace `A1` for the cell that you want and voilá

Answer (score 0):

In case you have to put string quote around A1

```
="INSERT INTO map.UserSurveys (surveyId,userId,activeQuestions) VALUES (50, '" & A1 & "', 1)"
```